# How to prove (given $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B \to C$), if $g∘ f\colon A \to C$ is onto, then $g$ is onto; if $g∘ f $ is 1to1, then $f$ is 1to1

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I am doing practice problems for my exam, and I can't seem to figure this one out.

Let :  → , : → . Prove that:

(a) if  ∘ :  →  is onto, then  is onto

(b) if  ∘ :  →  is one-to-one, then  is one-to-one

I know onto means surjectivity, and one-to-one means injectivity, but the  ∘  part is throwing me off. How would I go about proving this? We weren't given examples like this in class, but it is on our review sheet as concepts we should know.

Would it mean  ∘  is $A\to C$, or something else...

Thanks for guidance. If you have a proof, that would be helpful as well

Comment: The notation $g\circ f$ just means applying $g$ after $f$, so this indeed culminates in a function from $A$ to $C$, by, for all $a\in A$, $(g\circ f)(a)=g(f(a))\in C$.

Answer (score 2):

Those are just (straighforward?) applications of the definitions:

(a) Lef $c\in C$ be arbitrary. We want to find $b\in B$ such that $g(b)=c$.
As $g\circ f $ is onto, there exists $a\in A$ with $(g\circ f)(a)=c$. Let $b=f(a)$ (which is $\in B$). Then $g(b)=g(f(a))=(g\circ f)(a)=c$, thus showing that $g$ is onto.

(b) Assume $f(a)=f(a')$ for some $a,a'\in A$. We want to show that $a=a'$. We have $(g\circ f)(a)=g(f(a))=g(f(a'))=(g\circ f)(a')$ and as $g\circ f$ is 1-to-1, this tells us $a=a'$ as desired. Hence $f$ is 1-to-1.

Answer (score 0):

** Hint:**

Prove the contra-positive; if $g$ is *not* surjective (resp. if $f$ is not  injective), then …